# How to concatenate path to base url when a url redirects?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a request to:

`http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index1.html`

According to the arguments I sent, I'm getting a redirect to one of this two:
`http://www.baseaddress.com/path2/`
OR
`http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index2.html`

The problem is that the respond returns only:
`index2.html` or `/path2/`

for now I check if the first char is `/`, and concatenate the URL according to this.
Is there a simple method for doing this without string checking?

the code:

```
url = new URL("http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index1.php");
con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
... some settings
in = con.getInputStream();
redLoc = con.getHeaderField("Location"); // returns "index2.html" or "/path2/"
if(redLoc.startsWith("/")){
  url = new URL("http://www.baseaddress.com" + redLoc);
}else{
  url = new URL("http://www.baseaddress.com/path/" + redLoc);
}
```

do you think this is the best method?

Comment: Please can you show your code for the best answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [java.net.URI.resolve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29) to determine the redirected absolute URL.

```
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI ("http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index1.html");
System.out.println (uri.resolve ("index2.html"));
System.out.println (uri.resolve ("/path2/"));
```

Output

```
http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index2.html
http://www.baseaddress.com/path2/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!url.contains("index2.html"))
{
   url = url+"index2.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java class [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) function `resolve` to merge these URIs.

```
public String mergePaths(String oldPath, String newPath) {
    try {
        URI oldUri = new URI(oldPath);
        URI resolved = oldUri.resolve(newPath);
        return resolved.toString();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        return oldPath;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(mergePaths("http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index.html", "/path2/"));
System.out.println(mergePaths("http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index.html", "index2.html"));
```

Will output:

```
http://www.baseaddress.com/path2/
http://www.baseaddress.com/path/index2.html
```